# Download count only updates and displays the first row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download

I have this PHP/Jquery script that can show the total count of downloading the file. The problem is, it only shows the count in the first row same as every time I download a file, it only updates the first row. The image is shown below. But if I click the other rows, it still updates but it doesn't display/update the download count.

**Index.php**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>'.$i.'</td>
        <td>'.$row["title"].'</td>
        <td>
        <button id="dl_file" data-rid="'.$row['record_id'].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
        /** This Part **/
        <small><i>Downloads:<span id="dl_count" data-rid="'.$i.'" data-dlid="'.$row['record_id'].'"></span></i></small>
        
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dlid=$('#dl_count').attr("data-dlid");
    dl_count(dlid);
    load_data(1);
    function load_data(page, query = ''){
        var did=$('#dl_count').attr("data-dlid");
        $.ajax({
            url:"function/fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{page:page, query:query},
            success:function(data){
                if(query == ''){
                    $('#dynamic_content').html('');
                    dl_count(did);
                }else{
                    $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
                    dl_count(did);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});




$(document).on("click", "#dl_file", function() { 
    var rid=$(this).attr("data-rid");
    var dlid=$('#dl_count').attr("data-dlid");
    $.ajax({
        url: "function/downloads.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            record_id: rid,
        },
        success: function(result){
                dl_count(dlid);
        console.log(result);
        }
    });
});

/**************
 * 
 * Download Count
 *
 * *************/
 function dl_count(dlid){
    var dlid=$('#dl_count').attr("data-dlid");
    $.ajax({
        url: "function/dl_count.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { dl_count:1,dlid:dlid},
        success: function(data){
            $("#dl_count").html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

[image: Output - It only displays and updates the first row]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows in your table have same `span id` and when you perform `$("#dl_count").html(data);`

Your browser finds the first span with id = dl_count and changes its html content.

Here's a quick JSfiddle that would help you understand your problem [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Suri45/zwnbmsud/)

You can solve this problem by having individual `id` for each row, something like concatenating  id name with `$i` , like this `#dl_count . $is`.
Or
You can use the field `data-rid` to distinguish each row.

Comment: I've tried adding the data-rid but still, it doesn't show. This is how it should happen, it's from a table so it will show the search results. So in everytime I click the download button, the download count must update too.

Comment: can you tell me the span id for few rows in your table (the one near the "Download" text )  ?

Comment: <span class="dl_count" id="dl_count-1" data-rid="1" data-dlid="23"></span>
<span class="dl_count" id="dl_count-2" data-rid="2" data-dlid="22"></span>

Comment: ok, now that you have different ids, you will need to modify the statement in your ajax's success body from  `$("#dl_count").html(data);`  to something, which, can select your corresponding ID.

Since you are access data-rid, you can modify the previous statement to 

$("#dl_count"+ ( value of data-rid )).html(data);

Comment: quick edit, I assumed, you created the ids, by concatenating `'dl_count-' + $i`

Comment: I appreciate your effort in helping me but idk why it still won't work. This is what I've done on the dl_count function but still, it alerts one (#dl_count-1) <- this is what it shows on the alert box. 
This is the codes I used : [link] https://pastebin.com/3GHyMFh9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234412/discussion-between-dabin-tsikin-and-ford-prefect).